# Where is httpd.conf?

Tags: configuration, apache-httpd

How can I reliably find the location of httpd.conf?

I am looking for a solution, or if necessary a combination of things that will find the location of httpd.conf quickly and reliably on as many Operating Systems as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: `find / -name "httpd.conf"` ? or `apache2 -V` that gives something like `SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/apache2/apache2.conf"`?

Comment: That's not bad, but could be very slow in a big filesystem.  Perhaps there are very common places for httpd.conf that could limit where we look?  Or perhaps httpd.conf location is always somewhere relative to some other apache thing?

Comment: I was hoping there was an apache2 command that just told you where it was.

Comment: I installed apache24 on FreeBSD via pkg, but both "apache2" and "apache24" are not commands.  Now I'm trying to find *that*.

Comment: It looks like `apachectl -V` is working for me on both OSX and FreeBSD.

Comment: "Any OS" explicitly including Windows?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz That wouldn't be useful for me personally.  But for general usefulness to people, I was looking for "as many OSes as possible".  I'll change the question to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me,

`apachectl -V`

works on both OSX and FreeBSD.

If anybody has a better answer or a continuation of this answer for other operating systems, feel free to share.